# Read 1 GB file from ADLS in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to load a 1 GB csv file present in ADLS Gen2 from Databricks.
My cluster configuration is

Databricks Runtime:9.1 LTS(Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

Worker type : Standard 56 GB Memory 8 Core Min Worker 2 Max Worker 8

Driver node same as worker.

While loading the file to dataframe, I am getting error:

**The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will automatically re atttached.**

Earlier I was getting **Java Heap Space issue**
thats why I increased the Size of cluster to 56 GB but now also its not working.

Is there any other method to load the data to dataframe or some configuration change that will load the data

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a matter of hardware. You are probably using improper arguments for the read operation

Comment: How did you load the data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the CSV using spark.read ?

Try always using spark in databricks and try to apply repartition when loading this data. Spark will not load it until you apply some action over this DF. so try to apply this before any other action. This may help spark to run operations in parallel:

```
df = df.repartition(64)
```